# Plug-in for Eclipse that can zoom in

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

I have the Android SDK version of Eclipse (downloaded http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

I'd like to have a functionality in Eclipse which will allow me to *zoom in with CTRL + mouse scroll* the same way it is possible in the Chrome browser.

I found out that in the Android SDK version of Eclipse I can't use the "Eclipse Marketplace".
What I do have is an option called "Android SDK manager", but I can't find in it the library that has a plug-in which will allow me the functionality I've described above.

I would very much appreciate if anyone could assist me.

Thanks in advance,
Adam.

Comment: I presume you have not tried going to Help > Eclipse MarketPlace?
That link you have sent sends you to download the Android SDK "FOR" eclipse.. not Eclipse.

Comment: I've managed to install the Eclipse Marketplace. In there, there is this plugin called tarlog-plugins 1.4.2 which apparently does what I need, but has no download option, except as a .JAR file from gitHub link. Can you tell me how do I install a plugin from a .JAR file? Thank you, Adam

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any plugin that can do that, you would be able to google it just like me.

However you should realize that also the Eclipse Marketplace is a plugin, which first needs to be installed. It simply is not, in the Eclipse you get packaged with the Android SDK.

You can go to Help -> Install new software  and in the box where you type the URL, you can click the arrow to show a dropdown and it will have some pre-set links. One of them, is the standard link of your Eclipse version (should be Juno for you). Click that and let it load for a while.

You'll get a load of plug-ins. Look for something like 'General purpose tools' and in that you can find the Market Place plugin.

Once that is installed, it will be added in the Help menu.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I've managed to install the Eclipse Marketplace. In there, there is this plugin called **tarlog-plugins 1.4.2** which apparently does what I need, but has no download option, except as a .JAR file from gitHub [link](https://code.google.com/p/tarlog-plugins/downloads/detail?name=tarlog.eclipse.plugins_1.4.2.jar&can=2&q=). Can you tell me how do I install a plugin from a .JAR file? Thank you, Adam.